# Difference Between Zero-Dimensional and Totally Separated in the Plane

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, plane-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

In Michael Coornaert's book 'Topological Dimension and Dynamical Systems' he mentions the existence of a set $X$ in the plane that is totally separated, but not zero-dimensional.  He says it is due to Sierpinski, but the paper he cites is in French.  The example doesn't seem to be in Steen & Seebach; is anyone familiar?

Here, 'totally separated' means that the quasicomponents of $X$ are points.  Equivalently, for any $x, y \in X$ there is a separation of $X$ into disjoint open sets $U, V$ such that $x \in U$ and $y \in V$.

The Sierpinski paper is here: https://eudml.org/doc/212954

A zero-dimensional space in this context can equivalently mean a space with a clopen basis, a space all of whose points have a clopen basis, or a space with arbitrarily fine covers by disjoint open sets.

EDIT: David Hartley below has described Sierpinski's space satisfying the desired requirements.  I've attached a (bad) drawing.

[image]

Comment: What notion of dimension are you using?

Comment: Since we are in the separable metric case, any of the standard definitions will do.  Covering, small ind, big ind or scattered.

Comment: I was wondering if the Cantor set counted as an example.

Comment: But can you also provide, for sake of completeness, an explicit description for zero dimensionality?

Comment: Can you post a link to the paper by Sierpinski?

Comment: Posted now, thanks for any help!

Comment: @JohnSamples I find it odd that the "standard" definitions of dimension are the covering and inductive dimension. In my line of work, the Hausdorff and Minkowski dimensions are far more standard. :P I don't read French, but the construction in the paper looks to be similar to the construction of the standard [Sierpinski carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet) (thought it isn't quite that–the carpet fails to be totally separated).  You may find [this](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319197937-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1513804-p177405633) useful.

Comment: Still not sure about the Sierpinski example, but apparently the Erdos Space, which has the desired properties, was shown to be embeddable in the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example in the Sierpinski paper quoted is quite different from his carpet, except it also uses lots of rectangles. Here's a brief sketch of the construction. It uses repeated applications of the following procedure, illustrated on the rectangle with corners at $(\pm1,\pm1)$.   Let $R(2n-1)$ be the rectangle in the top-left quarter bounded by $y=0,y=1,x=-(2^{-(2n-2)})$ and $x=-(2^{-(2n-1)})$. Let $R(2n)$ be the matching rectangle 
in the bottom-right quarter (rotate 180 about origin). The same procedure, 
scaled appropriately, is repeated in each $R(n_1)$ to give rectangles $R(n_1,n_2)$ and again within those, and so on, giving $R(n_1, n_2,..,n_k)$ for any natural k.

Let $S_k$ be the union of all these rectangles with k indices and P be the 
intersection of all $S_k$. Let Q be the set containing the centres of all the 
defined rectangles and $E = P \cup Q$.

$E$ is totally separated but not zero-dimensional. In particular, any clopen 
set containing the centre of the outer rectangle has the mid-points of the 
top and bottom sides in its closure in $\mathbb R^2$ (they are not in $E$) and so has 
diameter at least 2. Hence the centre point cannot have a nbhd. basis of clopen sets.

Adding one of those mid-points to $E$ forms $E_1$ which cannot be totally 
separated but remains totally disconnected.

Comment: Should the exponents for the $x$-coordinates be negative?

Comment: Ok, this space works!  Thanks!  The details for the non-zero-dimensionality are a bit unpleasant; do you prefer to post them or should I go ahead?

Comment: Yes, they should be negative. I'll change them. (I tried to simplify the original as I'm not much good with Tex, but I slipped up there.)

Comment: I didn't make it clear that this is not my example, just a "translation" of the one in the Sierpinski paper. I'll have a go at the proof if you like, but it will have to wait to tonight.

Comment: if you can I would appreciate it, I have been MSEing on nothing but a tablet this summer (touch screen keyboard).  I deserve a new badge haha